# Nodejs wait in a Loop

Tags: node.js, wait, idioms

I would like to wait in a loop, what is the best way to achieve this ?

Here is my actual code :

```
var groups = ['461', '6726', '3284', '4', '121', '11', '399', '1735', '17', '19', '1614 ];
groups.forEach(function (value) {
            myfunction(value);
        });
```

I would like that myfunction() being called each 5 minutes.

I would like to loop through the groups array once and waiting between each item until the end is read

What is the best way ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're expecting exactly. Are you wanting to loop through the whole groups array every 5 mins or loop through the groups array once, waiting 5 minutes in between each item until the end is reached?

Comment: Hi. I would like to loo^p through the groups array once and waiting between each item until the end is ready.

Comment: I'm trying to use set.interval but i don't found a way to stop it when i passed through the whole groups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using setTimeout():

```
var groups = ['461', '6726', '3284', '4', '121', '11', '399', '1735', '17', '19', '1614'];
function nextGroup(idx) {
  idx = idx || 0;
  if (idx < groups.length) {
    myfunction(groups[idx]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      nextGroup(idx + 1);
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
  }
}
nextGroup();
```

Answer (score 9):

### 2017 Update

With es6, promises and async/await there are some nice ways to do this now. For example:

**Using async/await:**

```js
const groups = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function wait(milleseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milleseconds))
}

async function send(groups) {
  for (item of groups) {
    await wait(500)
    console.log(item)
  }
}
send(groups)
```

**Using the iterator protocol with setInterval**

```js
const groups = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

const intv = setInterval(gen => {
  const n = gen.next()
  if (n.done) return clearInterval(intv)

  console.log(n.value)
}, 500, groups[Symbol.iterator]())
```